# Android AutoCompleteTextView, how to link suggestions to xml?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the suggestions of my AutoCompleteTextView can be click to view my xml layouts.

I have done the xml part.

```
AutoCompleteTextView
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:text="Enter keyword to search outlet"
```

So here are my suggestions :

> static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Adidas", "Affin", "Alam Art" };

I have them saved as adidas.xml, affin.xml and alamart.xml. So how do i have them to be displayed with the autocomplete?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you are asking for :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html